# How can I change the text or image inside a card

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am new with flutter . I am trying to create a card view with smooth page indicator package and I am trying to have a different text or image inside each different card. Right now it gives all the same for all cards. How can I get it ?

[Card View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxqyn.png)

Comment: It's better to put your code in here (at least `PageView` widget), so someone can copy and test the code.

Comment: as far as I know from your image, you are generating a list of 3 cards with 3 static value. What you need to do is to create dynamic values and assign those to your Text widget and Image widget.